# I want "Sync Now" button in Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

What should I do now?

There is no way I would disconnect and reconnect from Ubuntu One.  What an idiot!

Comment: What is the problem? What happened?

Comment: This question is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly do you need, but it might be one of:

```
u1sdtool --wait
u1sdtool --refresh-shares
u1sdtool --start
```

See `man u1sdtool` for more details.